# MySQL get multiple rows and columns using procedures

Tags: mysql

the query below should return the data from database with multiple rows and multiple column without using procedures in mysql

**My code:**

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN @country_count < 8 THEN
    (SELECT * FROM country where country_id =1)
ELSE
    (SELECT * FROM country where country_id > 1)
END;
```

Comment: What is this `@country_count`?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Could you rephrase it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `SELECT *` as an expression -- when a subquery is used as an expression, it must return one row and one column.

You should put the test of `@country_count` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM country
WHERE CASE WHEN country_count < 8
        THEN country_id = 1
        ELSE country_id > 1
    END
```